# supremum and disjoint sets

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $S \subseteq R$ has the property that for any subset $A \subset S$, $sup A \in A$. Show that for any $a \in S$ there exists $b$ such that $b<a$, and $(b,a) \cap S = \emptyset$.

Where do I start with this? Should I start of considering the subset $(b,a)$ but how do I deduce the disjointness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $a\in S$ and assume that for every $b<a$ we can find some $x_b\in(b,a)\cap S$.

Then $A:=\{x_b\mid b<a\}$ is a subset of $S$ and evidently $\sup A=a\notin A$.

A contradiction is found, showing that some $b<a$ must exist with $(b,a)\cap S=\varnothing$.

This works for every fixed $a\in S$, so you are ready.